# How to programatically change application's notification settings?

Tags: macos, notifications, settings, development

There are some applications like WhatsApp or Telegram that don't have a fast way of disabling notifications.

I would like to know if it's possible to change notification settings programatically. In my case it would suffice to change the "Allow Notifications" toggle. I want to set a shortcut or make a script to enable/disable notifications for certain apps.

Just in case, here is a screenshot of the settings I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: I can see a great case for having a droplet you can set notification status/fine-tuning with [I've no clue how to do it, but I can definitely see the use-case here;)

Comment: btw, Pro Tip: After Cmd/Shift/4 for screen capture, hit the Spacebar, then you can with one click capture an entire window, with nifty little drop-shadow too. Very pretty ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Big Sur** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

All you should need to do is set the *value* of `targetApp`, at the start of the *script*, to the *name* of the *target application* as it's shown in the **Notifications** *pane* in **System Preferences**.

As currently coded the *script* toggles the **Allow Notification** *button* of the `targetApp`.

The *script* can be use in a number of different ways to trigger it, as an **AppleScript** *application*, as an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*, as a *shell script* by adding a `#!/usr/bin/osascript` *shebang* to the top of it, saving it as a *plain text file* and making it executable with `chmod`, or any *third-party utility* capable of running **AppleScript** *code*., etc.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
--  # Set the value of targetApp to the name of the
--  # target application as shown in the Notifications
--  # pane in System Preferences.

set targetApp to "Script Editor"


--  # Do not modify the code below unless necessary.

property |System Preferences| : name of ¬
    application id "com.apple.systempreferences"


--  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application id "com.apple.systempreferences" then
    try
        tell application id "com.apple.systempreferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall '" & |System Preferences| & "'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.

repeat while running of ¬
    application id "com.apple.systempreferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

--  # Open System Preferences to the Notifications pane.

tell application id "com.apple.systempreferences"
    run -- # Used as a workaround to an issue in Big Sur.
    delay 0.1
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.notifications"
end tell

--  # Use System Events to achieve the goal.

tell application id "com.apple.systemevents"
    run -- # Used as a workaround to an issue in Big Sur.
    delay 0.2
    tell window 1 of application process |System Preferences|
        
        --  # Wait for target pane to be available.
        
        my waitForUIelement(row -1 of table 1 of scroll area 1)
        
        --  # Ascertain the target row to select.
        
        set rowTargetApp to the first row of table 1 of ¬
            scroll area 1 whose value of static text 1 of ¬
            group 1 of UI element 1 is targetApp
        
        --  # Select the target row.
        
        select rowTargetApp
        
        --  # Wait for target checkbox to be available.
        
        my waitForUIelement(button 1 of group 1)
        
        --  # Click Allow Notifications.
        
        click button 1 of group 1
        
    end tell
end tell

delay 0.02

quit application id "com.apple.systempreferences"


--  ## Handler ##

on waitForUIelement(uiElement)
    tell application id "com.apple.systemevents"
        tell window 1 of application process ¬
            |System Preferences|
            set i to 0
            repeat until exists uiElement
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end waitForUIelement
```

**Notes:**

As currently coded the *script* just toggles the **Allow Notification** *button* of the `targetApp`, however, the *code* can be easily modified to check the state of the target *button* and act accordingly. As an example, if one wants to just be sure it's toggled off.

**Change:**

```applescript
click button 1 of group 1
```

**To:**

```applescript
if value of button 1 of group 1 is "on" then ¬
    click button 1 of group 1
```

---

For use in **macOS Catalina**:

**Change:**

```applescript
    --  # Ascertain the target row to select.
        
set rowTargetApp to the first row of table 1 of ¬
    scroll area 1 whose value of static text 1 of ¬
    group 1 of UI element 1 is targetApp
```

**To:**

```applescript
    --  # Ascertain the target row to select.
    
set rowTargetApp to first item of (rows of table 1 of ¬
    scroll area 1 whose value of static text 1 of ¬
    group 1 of UI element 1 is targetApp)
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>